# AC Dimmer circuit with MOC3021 & EL817 along with ESP8266 (NodeMCU)

Tags: voltage-regulator, esp8266, fan, dimmer

Major two issues/question are here:

1) **The challenge I am facing is, my `interrupt` is not working**.

2) **do I need to include a Heat Sink in this?**

Hello, I am quite new to electronics and trying to build an AC Dimmer Circuit. Here is the schematics (First one of my life) I have draw to show the circuit how I connected.

[image]

And I am using a simple programming through Arduino IDE. Here is the reference you can check the code below.

```
void ICACHE_RAM_ATTR zero_cross_detect();

int triac_pin = 14;  // Digital output to TRIAC
int dimm_time = 8000;  // 8000 = 20% output power
bool zero_cross = 0;
void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Power on...");
  pinMode(triac_pin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(triac_pin, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(triac_pin, LOW);
  Serial.println("Power off...");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("Start dimming...");
  attachInterrupt(12, zero_cross_detect, CHANGE);

}

void loop() {
  if (zero_cross) {
    if (dimm_time < 9500) {
      delayMicroseconds(dimm_time);
      digitalWrite(triac_pin, HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(200);
      digitalWrite(triac_pin, LOW);
    }
    zero_cross = 0;
  }

  if (dimm_time > 8800) {
    dimm_time = 9500;
  }
  if (dimm_time < 1000) {
    dimm_time = 1000;
  }

  if (Serial.available() > 1) {
    int getval = 10000 - (Serial.parseInt() * 100);
    if (getval >= 0 && getval <= 10000) {
      dimm_time = getval;
      Serial.print("Dimm to ");
      Serial.print(100 - (getval / 100));
      Serial.println(" %");
    } else {
      Serial.println("Wrong value!");
    }
  }
}

void zero_cross_detect() {  // If zero crossing is detected
  Serial.println("ZC");
  zero_cross = 1;
}
```

**The challenge I am facing is, my `interrupt` is not working**. I am using some wrong connection here? I have seen on YouTube and blogs lot of people are using 4N35 and even RoboDyn AC dimmer module uses 4N25. **Can I use EL817 instead?**

I am planning to do home fan speed control with this circuit.

One more question is, do I need to include a Heat Sink in this? And if yes. **Then how do I calculate what size of heat sink should be used in this?**

Thank you for help!

Comment: I don't see any pull up on the zero cross detector. Do you have an internal strong pull up within the MCU? If you don't have a scope, go buy one if those really cheap, $20, units and solder it together. They are adequate to verify your zero cross input. You need something to check that out.

Comment: Yes I guess with NodeMCU all the GPIO pins have pull up resistor in that. Do you think a pull up resistor can help in this? I will add a 10k resistor to this. @jonk

Comment: Think you are right. I forget to connect a resistor to EL817 pin 3 a resistor.

Comment: make the global variable set in interrupt volatile `volatile bool zero_cross = 0;` I tested the Robotdyn AC dimmer with 2 kW heater (240 V). Over 1.5 kW the triac overheated and didn't switch off at zero crossing.

Comment: @juraj What does `volatile ` will do in this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246127/why-is-volatile-needed-in-c

Comment: @Juraj thank you so much. These information helped me a lot. One more thing, can you please help me to understand what size of heat sink should be applied to handle load.

Comment: there is nothing about expected load in your question

Comment: `I am planning to do home fan speed control with this circuit.

One more question is, do I need to include a Heat Sink in this? And if yes. Then how do I calculate what size of heat sink should be used in this?

`

Comment: @juraj I got the problem solved by your suggestion of adding a Pull Up Resistor. I got this working. :) Thanks a lot!